# How to condense a randomly generated url into a small click here button

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am sending out an email with a verification code in it. Instead of the code showing in all one link the code breaks and the end of the string. I would like to be able to have that randomly generated code and url condensed into one click here button. I am not sure how I would accomplish this.

```
<%@URL%>/verify?Securedata=<%@Securedata$X%>
```

This is the code that is sent through email
When it arrives it looks like this:
http://ab.dev.loc/verify?Securedata= 6477564C3572756B.........Lots of numbers and letters here......

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `<a href="your link here">Click here to activate your account</a>` ?

Comment: I have tried this approach, the problem I find is that the a href doesn't recognized the front half of the URL. so I end up with something like this:     <a href="%@URL%/verify?Securedata=6477564C3572756

Comment: Sounds like a templating error on the server side rather than an issue with html or email client

Comment: It turns out to be a template error, Another user was editing the template I was using. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including `<` and `>` inside an html element? In that case, you should use HTML entities:

**<** = `&lt;`

**>** = `&gt;`

A complete list: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

```
&lt;%@URL%&gt;/verify?Securedata=&lt;%@Securedata$X%&gt;
```

Maybe some other characters need to be parse that way too.